# Retrieving valid photo URL from FB Graph API WITH an extension

Tags: image, facebook, file, facebook-graph-api, web

Using Facebook API and the picture data returned has a valid URL for the photo but it has no extension.  This is causing problems for my file upload.  How do I append an extension to the FB Photo URL or retrieve a FB photo URL with an extension?

API call:

```
me?fields=picture
"picture": {
    "data": {
      "height": 50,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=[somedata]&height=50&width=50&ext=[somedata]&hash=[somedata]",
"width": 50
    }
```

Comment: You can't. Fix your file upload code to handle URLs that doesn't end with an extension.

Comment: @WizKid  For security reasons Wordpress File Upload does not allow files without a proper extension from external URL's.

Comment: Then you will have to download the file somewhere add an extension and then upload that file. There is no way to tell Facebook to add an extension